# Получить адрес нужного модуля в другом приложении

Tags: c++, winapi, процесс

Задача такова - нужно получить адрес нужного мне модуля в чужом приложении из моего приложения. 
Мои попытки:

```
const HANDLE process_controll::ProcessControll::getProcessHandle(const tstring & processName, const DWORD& accessFlag)
{
    return OpenProcess(accessFlag, false, getID(processName));
}

DWORD getModuleAdrEx(const TCHAR * processName, TCHAR* moduleName)
{
    HANDLE procHandle = t_proc.getProcessHandle(processName);
    if (!procHandle) { msg_er_full; return 0; }

    HMODULE module{};
    if (!GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS, moduleName, &module)) { msg_er_full; return 0; }

    MODULEINFO moduleInf{};
    if (GetModuleInformation(procHandle, module, &moduleInf, sizeof(MODULEINFO)) == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    CloseHandle(procHandle);
    return moduleInf.lpBaseOfDll;
}
```

Собственно функция `GetModuleInformation`возвращает "неудачу", ну и соответственно в `moduleInf.lpBaseOfDll` - 0.

p.s. ID процесса 100% верно всегда находит, handle процесса тоже не равен 0, GetModuleHandleEx возвращает "правду".

Comment: А GetLastError что говорит после неудачи с GetModuleInformation?

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, не верный дискриптор, хотя я проверял - и хендл процесса не равен 0 и модуль возвращает не равным нулю

Comment: А код какой числом?

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, ну я ж расшифровал, что означает этот код - неверный дескриптор.

Comment: Да вы числом скажите, или имя ERROR_

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, - 0x6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ оказался прост,кому интересно, прилагаю код:

```
std::vector<MODULEENTRY32> process_controll::ProcessControll::getModuleListFromProcess(tstring processName)
{
    std::vector<MODULEENTRY32> containerModule{};

    MODULEENTRY32 MdlEntry{};

    MdlEntry.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);

    HANDLE pMdlSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, getID(processName));

    if (!pMdlSnap) {

        return std::vector<MODULEENTRY32>();
    }

    while (Module32Next(pMdlSnap, &MdlEntry)) {

        containerModule.push_back(MdlEntry);
    }

    if (CloseHandle(pMdlSnap) == 0) { msg_er_full; }

    return containerModule;
}
```

Использование:

```
for (auto it : t_proc.getModuleListFromProcess(_T("processName")))
    {
        console("%#x", it.modBaseAddr);
    }
```

Comment: Имхо, хорошо бы ошибку описать словесно.

Comment: Дело-то в чем было?

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов - я так и не разобрался в чем ошибка была моего первого способа - я просто нашел альтернативный рабочий вариант!